# Disable loading Thumbnail On Mobile

Tags: post-thumbnails, mobile

I am looking for a script or plugin that disable loading thumb in mobile browser but load thumb on desktop browser.

Clearly, in a wordpress website, if I visit a website in desktop browser then website homepage post will load thumb and if I visit this site in mobile browser then website homepage post will not load thumb.

How can I stop loading thumb in mobile? Thanks in advanced. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Use CSS media queries

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  /* if its not mobile */
  if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
  /* load and show the post thumbnail */
     the_post_thumbnail();
  }
?>
```

You can read on wp_is_mobile [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) and on the the_post_thumbnail [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: wp_is_mobie is a bad thing to use as you should not detect device type on server side, just on client side. It might specifically break caching depending on how the caching is done.